# Inline html deleted from blogdown page

Tags: markdown, hugo, blogdown

I have the following line of html code in a markdown (.md) file.

```html
<a href="https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-401-finance-theory-i-fall-2008/#">Finance Theory I</a>
```

When I use blogdown to build the site, the text "Finance Theory I" is rendered without a hyperlink. I understand that I could use markdown hyperlinks instead. This is a simple example of a larger problem where none of my inline html is being rendered.

Comment: Your link text is "Finance Theory I", yet you say that the text "Finance Theory" is rendered. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a side effect of Hugo adopting [Goldmark](https://github.com/yuin/goldmark/) as the default Markdown rendering library. This was [introduced in Hugo v0.60](https://gohugo.io/news/0.60.0-relnotes/).

To have the Goldmark renderer emit HTML embedded in your Markdown add the following to your site config. This comes from the Hugo release notes linked above:

```
[markup]
  [markup.goldmark]
    [markup.goldmark.renderer]
      unsafe = true
```

Using this setting in a test site with your html and the `ananke` theme used in the initial Hugo walkthrough produced a link as expected with transformed markdown around it.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you had given the HTML tag as like on MD file, by default Hugo will render the MD format file to HTML. So please our some online tool to convert HTML to MD and paste on the MD file which will work fine for you

https://stackedit.io/app#